# MongoDB query for Find 2 levels object element

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a big issue, i don't know what to do...

What I wanna is to find all objects with Object2 name. I have `Object 2` with name element.

What I wanna is to find all objects with the value X in the element name inside `Object2`. in the example is the value name is =`"IWANTALLOBJECTSWITHTHISNAME"`

the Json structure.

```
"objects": [
        {
            "_id": "5c69a62cf9acf00d00dbc02d",
            "date": "2222-02-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "22",
            "Object1": {
                "_id": "5c69a62cf9acf00d00dbc02b",
                "date": "2222-02-24T00:00:00.000Z",
                "user": "5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee",
                "positionsObject1": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "Object2": {
                             "_id":"5c69a62cf9acf00d00dbc02c",
                             "name": "IWANTALLOBJECTSWITHTHISNAME"
                         },
                        "description": "22",
                        "value": 22
                    }
                ],
                "id": 13,
                "__v": 0
            },
            "user": "5c30fd5890bbd24a1c46c7ee",
            "id": 7,
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
```

I'm new in mongoDB and this query is really really hard. I tried everything. Thank very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the path using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/):

```
db.col.find({ "objects.Object1.positionsObject1.Object2.name": "IWANTALLOBJECTSWITHTHISNAME" })
```

Comment: thx mickl for your help, i see it works when is all the collection agruped. But i don't undestand why i can't access to any Object with the dot. Even the Obj1.id

Comment: I need more details to help you, could you use mongoplayground.net to create an example with your data set where it does not work as expected ?

Comment: aah i think its because Obj1 and Obj2 are in diferent collections i only have the ObjId. I paste mongoplay with a better example. i wanna all obj1 with the obj2.num = 1231231. for the example https://mongoplayground.net/p/xak_cAzgaig

Comment: Well this means that what you posted current question and answer are far away from what you want to achieve. Maybe you can create a new question to make it clear that you need to "merge" the data from multiple collections

Comment: Yes, okey i will do other question. Thx very much.